# ReactJS fetch() after component mounted, on change

Tags: reactjs

Most examples shows ReactJS `fetch()` in `componentDidMount`. In my example, I need a fetch as part of a state change received from another component, after initialization (initially my component is empty). I currently do it in `render()` which is always called on a state change.

But something's wrong: the Fetch works and the `render()` is called on the  state change, but `return <div>..</div>` doesn't output, so I don't see my rendered HTML.

**Component**

```
componentDidMount() {   
    /* Nothing here. The component should initially be empty. */    
}   

render() {
    
    const { study, items } = this.props;
    
    // THIS WORKS Another component triggers this one's state change, I get the alert
    alert('State changed: ' + study);
    
    if (study) {
        /* Ajax call in render(). The fetch works as verified with console.log(result) */
        fetch("/api/myCall?id=" + study)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(
            (result) => {
                            return <div>RESULT OBTAINED</div>  <-- THIS DOESN'T WORK, result is OK
                        },
            (error)  => {
                            return <div>ERROR</div>
                        }
            );              
    } else {
        return <div>EMPTY</div>
    }
```

Comment: Dont do API requests in `render()`. Populate state after results are received by fetch and use state variable in render.

Comment: But who does the fetch? The parent component? and where?

Comment: Whatever goes inside `.then(...` is asynchronous. Small wonder you don't see anything. You need to update a state variable with those results and let the component re-render to see anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this to work you would have to block the rendering until the fetch is fullfilled, or manipulate the state of your component depending on the result/error, which in turn would cause another render and with it another fetch call so you would get an endless loop. So calling fetch directly inside render is never a good idea if your UI depends on the result.

Instead, use `componentDidUpdate()`, like this:

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
   const { study } = this.props;

   if(prevProps.study !== study){
       fetch("/api/myCall?id=" + study).then(result => {
           //Manipulate your state here!
       })
   }

}
```

This way you only request new data and update your components state when the `study` property, which is passed from outside, changes. No need to call fetch inside of render.

-- EDIT --

Alternatively you could also do the fetch in the other component and pass all the data you need via props to your component. That way you would have a stateless component which is easier to maintain.